# How to make side-by-side Python 2.7 and 3.2 installs on Ubuntu 12.04,

Tags: python, ubuntu-12.04, python3.2

I just installed Ubuntu 12.04 and Python 2.7 is pre-installed.  I want also to have 3.2, and to be able to select one as the default with no arguments and the other to be specified by command line argument.

I guess I'm asking how to set environment variables analogous to PATH in Windows7, right?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's impossible to use the command python using `python3.2` because Ubuntu uses `python2.7`. 
You can try using `#!/usr/bin/python3` in that first line of your python code to use `python3.2`.

To install `python3.2` in Ubuntu:

Go to the console and put this:

```
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install python3
```

After that, go to the console and enter `python3`. This will be `python3.2` and `python` will be `python 2.7`.

Comment: sorry I hadn't gotten around to `accepting` the answer until today.  i just received a notification that it was a `notable question`.  strange, but okay!